# Show convergence of sequence (fixed-point iteration)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

> Given $g(x) = 2\cdot \ln(x+1)$, show that there exists a $k>0$ so that $g(k)=k$  and the sequence $x_{n+1} := g(x_n)$ is convergent to such $k$.

I could just think of comparing the graphs.
Having $g(0)=0$ and considering that $g(1)>1$ as well as $g'(x)=\frac{2}{1+x}$ is soon getting smaller and smaller, the desired $k>0$ should come very "soon".

So calculating, I get $g(1)= 1.39$ and $g(2)=2.2$ and $g(3)=2.77$, an here one can see that there must be an intersection. So $k \in [2;3]$.

Now how can I show that $x_{n+1} := g(x_n)$ is convergent to this $k$?

Comment: Do you know Banach's fixed point theorem (also known as the contraction principle)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $g:[3/2,+\infty)\to [3/2,+\infty)$ is a [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping): for $x,y\geq 3/2$, by the MVT there is $t$ between $x$ and $y$ such that
$$|g(x)-g(y)|=|g'(t)||x-y|=\frac{2}{1+t}|x-y|\leq  \frac{4}{5}|x-y|.$$

P.S. Note that by the concavity of $g$, $g(x)\geq \ln(3)x$ in $[0,2]$, hence if the starting point $x_0\in (0,3/2)$ then, after a finite number of iterations, $x_n>3/2$.

Comment: Sorry this late, but how did you find the 4/5 so that $ \frac{2}{1+t} \leq \frac{4}{5}$?

Comment: @Vazrael $t\to\frac{2}{1+t}$ is decreasing. Now let $t=3/2$.

Comment: alright, but why exactly did you take "3/2" in the first place, so why restrict g on $[3/2, \infty]$ and not, for example, on $[0.1, \infty]$ or something like that?

Comment: For $[a,+\infty)$, I chose $a>0$ such that $\frac{2}{1+a}<1$. $a=3/2$ works, but it is not the only choice...

Comment: Okay, I got it. One last thing: Don't we need that $g$ is a function from $M$ to $M$, in this case (as you have chosen): $[3/2, \infty] \to [3/2, \infty]$, but it seems to me as if $g$ is only a function from $M$ to a subspace of $M$ (because $g(x) > 3/2$ for $x \in [3/2, \infty]$). Is this allowed for the Banach fix point theorem? Surjectivity is not needed, right?

Comment: No, we don't need surjectivity. Actually $g([3/2,+\infty))=[4/5,+\infty)$. Usually $g:A\to B$ means that $g(A)\subseteq B$.